# Blank value returned when referencing a custom field on a related custom object on the Account

Tags: formula, childrelationship

I have created a Lookup Relationship on the Account object to a custom object named Installation (API name Most_Recent_Installation__c).

I want to be able to show a field from this related object on the Account Page Layout and to do this created a custom formula field on the Account using the following formula:

Most_Recent_Installation__r.subdomain__c

Note the subdomain field is a Text(64) (Unique Case Insensitive) & is Indexed.

However no matter what I do I always get blank values displayed on the Account as well as when I query for this field using the Developer Console.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I have created a formula field on the Installation object itself referencing this field and can see the values

Comment: Is the lookup field populated with a value?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said that in the first place

Comment: Have you checked the Field Level Security of the lookup field in the account object?

Comment: It's set to Visible and Read Only as I'd expect